# Embedded images in EmailJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, nodemailer

I am using EmailJS, and I have created a form that requires the user to upload images from their device. I have taken these images and tried to add them to the template, but unfortunately, they are not getting added. Does EmailJS really support adding images? Should these images be processed or uploaded to a service to get a URL, or is it not necessary? These are all questions that anyone with answers to should please let me know because the task needs to be delivered to the client tomorrow, and it depends on these images. Help me, guys!

Note that I am using React.js, and I have tried sending the form using both sendForm and just form. If EmailJS supports sending images, what should be written in the React.js code, and what should be written in the Email Templates?

I tried adding the images locally within the frontend code only, but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an embedded image, simply insert the img tag and provide the CID (Content-ID) for the src attribute. Read this: https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/embedded-images/

```html
<img src="cid:YOUR_ATTACHMENT_CID" alt="attachment">
```

Also, you can upload the image to some server and use the link as the source.

And here how you can send the image as an attachment:

```js
function formSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', this);
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="formSubmit()">
    <label>Attach file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="my_file"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/file-attachments/